# Display message in Chrome if wrong type is entered in input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome (55.x) if a user attempts to enter mismatched type into an input (in my case a number input) nothing outwardly appears to happen. To enhance usability I'd like to display a popup to let users know they're trying to enter invalid data rather than have them thinking the input is 'broken'.

This is easily achieved with pure JS in FF (which allows mismatched type to be entered, it just isn't valid):

```
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
        this.value = '';
        console.log('please enter a number!');            
    }
}
```

Because Chrome doesn't actually input anything, however, the validity check always passes as the input is empty; it doesn't appear to do anything with the incorrect input except ignore it.

Is there any way to override this behaviour, or otherwise achieve the intended effect?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could do a listener for keyup and it will give you the key that was pressed.

```
<script>
    var numInput = document.getElementById("num");
    numInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
       if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
           alert("Must be a number");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd considered this method, but discounted it as it can get pretty messy - you have to take into account Delete and Backspace, as well as any keyboard shortcuts that can operate on the input field; instead of a nice, simple function you can rapidly end up with convoluted code. While I appreciate your answer (and it's more elegant than my code would have been), if it's choosing between that or the default behaviour I'm going to take the lazy option. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a last input value and check like this?

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let lastInput = input.value;
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === lastInput) {
        alert("Input must be a number");
    }
    lastInput = e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: Mismatched types don't make it to the input's value at all, `input.value` is always empty - specifically, using your code means the message pops up if valid numbers are deleted. The difficulty here is getting it to recognise the input's empty because it's been sent invalid data vs. it being empty due to a user deleting something.

Comment: So whenever input event happens, I updated lastInput so it can detect the deleting. I tried in chrome and seems like working with deleting.

Comment: Looks like I was a little mistaken - it may be due to a bug in Chrome, it's unusual behaviour. Use your code, type a letter into the field. You'll get the alert. The field will still be empty, and both `lastInput` and `target.value` have no value. Now press `Backspace` - you'll get the alert again. Not sure why this is happening, as there isn't anything to delete. I'm afraid I'm not going to accept this as the answer it isn't quite perfect, even though that's not your fault, but upvoted as it's a good attempt.